# Undefined offset: 245 phpmyadmin al insertar json

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente json en una  columna de mysql

```
{
    "links_normales": [{
        "item_submenu": "01"
    }, {
        "item_submenu": "02"
    }]
}
```

Cuando ingreso me sale
¡Se detectaron algunos errores en el servidor!
Revise el pie de esta ventana.

Y abajo
Notice in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#522
 Undefined offset: 245

Tengo:
Tipo de servidor: MySQL
Versión del servidor: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: ¿Qué versión de phpMyAdmin estás usando?

Comment: Acerca de esta versión: 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2

Comment: Hay un bug parecido en la versión 4.6.0, que está solucionado en la 4.6.1: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12132

Comment: ¿Has probado a actualizar a la última versión?